# Binding to a ExpandoObject in Blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, expandoobject

I've build a class which has a dynamic list of properties (such as color, size, weight etc etc), the contents of this aren't known at compile time so I used a `ExpandoObject`

Where I'm struggling is to get Blazor to bind to the value properties of the object for example

```
@foreach (var option in (IDictionary<string, object>)selectedProduct.Properties)
{
    <div class="col-sm">
        <input type="text" placeholder="@option.Key" @bind="option.Value"/>
    </div>
}
```

However when this is compiled the autogen code results in an error :- `'KeyValuePair<string, object>.Value' cannot be assigned to`

Has anyone had any success binding to a ExpandoObject (and children properties?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not directly related to the ExpandoObject.

When you iterate over a Dictionary you get back *immutable* KeyValuePair items.

You get an error because `@bind="option.Value"` compiles to code that wants to assign to `option.Value`.

And as tuples and anonymous types are all immutable I think you will have to write a `<Label, Value>` class for this.

Comment: Derp! Apparently I just need some coffee and aren't thinking straight. Thanks for point that out, I managed to fix it with `@onchange="@((ChangeEventArgs __e) => ((IDictionary<string, object>)selectedProduct.Properties)[option.Key] = (object)__e.Value.ToString())"`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Henk's answer I was able to modify my code to support the ExpandoObject

```
@foreach (var option in (IDictionary<string, object>)selectedProduct.Properties)
{
    <div class="col-sm">
        <input type="text" placeholder="@option.Key" @onchange="@((ChangeEventArgs __e) => ((IDictionary<string, object>)selectedProduct.Properties)[option.Key] = (object)__e.Value.ToString())"/>
    </div>
}
```

Its uglier to look at but does the job